# Web.Release.Config does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, web-config-transform

I have a web site I just took over and am wanting to get web transformations working. I have always had success with MVC projects doing this for debug and release but this ASP web pages application refuses to cooperate.

I apologize if this is a duplicate. I see a lot of questions like this but nothing has solved my issue yet.

If I press F5 and run, I get web.config settings as I expect.
If I publish my "Test" profile (debug mode) I get web.Test.Config transformations as expected.
If I publish my "Release" profile I get the same web.Test.Config transformations and NOT the release one.

Possible issues or things that may be of interest:

The web.config file expands in the solution to show the debug file. The release file is not part of this and is listed separately below.

I tried changing the compilation setting for debug to false in the main web.config. This had no effect.

In the SLN file I noticed that I have lines in the GlobalSection for postSolution that list my project GUID followed by .Debug or .Release. BOTH of these say "Debug|Any CPU" at the end. I changed the release ones to say "Release|Any CPU". I republished but VS just changed this back to Debug on me.

In Build -> Configuration Manager, I select Release as thje Active soltion configuration. In the Project contexts box, my application only has Debug available in the Configuration column drop down.

Edit: I noticed that in website.publishproj there was no section for Release. There was a PropertyGroup with configuration of Debug but that's all. Being cavalier or stupid I ignored the "do not modify this file" message and added the release section. This had no effect.

Edit: Photo pasted in. The dropdown is expanded. [image: Build configuration screen]

Comment: Do you have multiple projects in the solution? You might have either deleted the release config of the problem project or added a release to another project but not to the problem one. You should be able to see in configuration manager what exactly is happening. You should also be able to add the release build back in inside config manager but I would rename or delete the transform file first and ask it to create it again.

Comment: An alternative is to create a new empty project that is similar and doing a diff between the two to see if you've accidentally modified any other files but the project file should contain everything it needs.

Comment: Only one project in the solution. I deleted the release configuration from build manager and added a new one. The problem is that I can only select debug in the drop down box for the project contexts.

Comment: Did you definitely add a project configuration or just a solution one? The solution one maps onto various project ones but if there is only one project config, then every solution configuration will map onto debug. You add a project one in Configuration Manager in the dropdown list next to the project, not at the top.

Comment: "Dropdown list next to the project"? Not following. I have three ways of getting there: "Release/Debug" drop down, "CPU Type" drop down, and Build menu. All say "Active solution configuration". Same result if I right click on the solution to get there (4th way). There's no option on the project to get to a configuration manager.

Comment: Build->Configuration Manager

Comment: That's my third item I mentioned. Only DEBUG is available to select from.

Answer (score 0):

The highlighted dropdown is where you would need to add the configuration back in:

[image]

Comment: Or in the Active solution configuration depending on which one is missing (not sure now!). Both dropdowns should have "New..." in.

Comment: That drop down contains "Debug" only. Nothing else

Comment: Then I can only guess! Are the solution or the project files read-only on disk and/or are you debugging? My dialog looks slightly different in VS 2015 so I can't see if your solution dropdown is disabled. Have you closed/reopen VS to see if any information is cached by the IDE? Sorry I can't be more help!

Comment: I found the issue. There is no CSPROJ file. I don't know how this thing even runs and works. The solution file contains:
*Project("guid") = "AppName", ".", "guid"*
That period in the middle should be the CSPROJ file. But there is none. I took this application over from another developer. I didn't know you could have an application without this file.

Comment: You should answer your own question then so other people can find it!

Comment: I only suspect the missing CSPROJ is the issue. I don't know how to regenerate the file. Until I get it working I won't answer the question.